# wp get tags in custom query loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm stuck! I'm trying to render out the 'tags' for each post. The posts are split up into categories. I didn't build this site and I'm having trouble working with it. 
I trying using the_tag() , but because its a custom query loop. I don't think that will work.

here is how the loop starts

```
<?php 
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$term = get_field('news_category');
$number = get_field('number_of_posts_per_page');


$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => $number,
'paged' => $paged,

));
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="hider col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-item">
   <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'news' ); ?>
</div> 

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

ANY help would be great, I'm so lost right now!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you used `the_tag()`, the function is called `the_tags()`?

Also, did you use `the_tags()` inside the loop?

```php
<?php 

    // Reformatted code

    $paged   =  ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    // ACF Plugin related function
    $term    =  get_field('news_category');
    $number  =  get_field('number_of_posts_per_page');

    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $number,
        'paged'          => $paged,
    ));

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ($the_query->have_posts()) :

            $the_query->the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="hider col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 grid-item">
           <?php get_template_part( 'parts/loop', 'news' ); ?>
        </div> 

        <?php

            the_tags(); // Inside the loop

        endwhile;

    endif;

?>
```

Comment: thank for the reply, yes i used the_tags() inside the loop. being that it's a custom query, would I have to query the tags inside 'new Query' array?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to select posts by tag, then yes. But since you stated you want to render the tags, `the_tags()` should work in order to print the tags to HTML, I tested it. However, if you don't have tags attached to a post, `the_tags()` renders nothing at all.

Comment: I'm on WP Engine, so I'm double checking to see if staging vs production has anything to do with it. I did add the tags in staging, but maybe they need to be added in production.

Comment: yeah, so that was it. I needed to add the tags to the post through 'production', thanks for all your help!

Comment: Omg. Nice to help, glad you found it!